# One sided limit of an integral of a regulated function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I am working on the following exercise:

> Consider a non-negative regulated function $\phi$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) dx = 1$$
> and let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \ a_n \rightarrow \infty.$$
> Show that the sequence $(\delta_n(x))_n$ defined by $\delta_n(x) := a_n\phi(a_nx)$ is a Dirac-Sequence. Use this to show that
> $$lim_{h \rightarrow 0+} \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{h}{h^2+x^2}f(x) \ dx = f(0)$$
> , where $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a in $0$ continuous regulated function.

I do not know how to do this. Could you help me?

EDIT: Here is the terminology:

> [Regulated-Function:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulated_function) Let $I$ be an interval with starting point $a$ and endpoint $b$. A function $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a regulated function on $I$ if
>
> 1. In every point $x \in (a,b)$ exists the left and the right limit.
> 2. If $a \in I$ then $f$ has a rigt limit in $a$. If $b \in I$ then $f$ has a left limit in $b$.
>
> Dirac-Sequence: A sequence $(\delta_k)_k$ of regulated functions on $\mathbb{R}$ is called Dirac Sequence if:
>
> 1. $\delta_k \ge 0$ for all $k$
> 2. $\int_\mathbb{R} \delta_k (t) dt = 1$ for all $k$
> 3. For arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ and $r>0$ exists an $N$ such that for all $k \ge N$ holds:
>    $$\int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus [-r,r]} \delta_k(t) dt < \epsilon$$
>    $$\bigg\lvert \int_{[-r,r]} \delta_k(t) dt -1 \bigg\rvert < \epsilon$$

Comment: you must explain some terminology..what is a dirac sequence and a regulated function?

Comment: I'll do an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: checking that $\delta_k(x)\geq0$\

$\delta_k(x)=a_k\phi(a_k x)$  is a product of two positive numbers for any $x$ and all $k$ hence $\delta_k(x)\geq 0$.
Step 2: showing that $\int_{R}\delta_k(x)\, dx=1$
$$
\int_{R}\delta_k(x)\, dx= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} a_k \phi(a_k x)\, dx=[a_k x=y]= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(y)\, dy=1
$$
Step 3:
$$
|\int_{-\infty}^{-r}a_k\phi(a_k x)\, dx +\int_{r}^{\infty} a_k\phi(a_k x) \, dx |\leq \epsilon$$
$$
| \int_{-\infty}^{-r}a_k\phi(a_k x)\, dx +\int_{r}^{\infty} a_k\phi(a_k x) \, dx +\int_{-r}^{r} a_k\phi(a_k x) \, dx -\int_{-r}^{r} a_k \phi(a_k x)\, dx|=
$$
$$
= |1-\int_{-r}^{r} a_k \phi(a_k x)\, dx| \leq \epsilon
$$
Step 4: showing the main integral
Re-writing
$$
\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}=\frac{1}{h}\frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{h})^2}
$$
And substitute $x=yh$ where $y \in \mathbb{R}$ we get
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+y^2}f(hy) \, dy
$$
According to mclaurin approximation we have that $f(hy)=f(0)$ as $h \to 0$ hence we get
$$
\frac{f(0)}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+y^2} \, dy=\frac{f(0)}{\pi}(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2})=f(0)
$$
Tada you are done.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the answer? Pls let me know so that I can fix it.

Comment: I am reading it right now, I ll let you know.

Comment: I am sure know that your answer is correct Tamim. Thanks for your help.